# How to get rid of windows sounds when capturing CTRL + S?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-7, audio

In my application, when I press `CTRL + S`, my form (with Key Preview enabled) captures this and saves the document. But when the focus is in, for example, an edit control, I get an annoying "Ding" sound, or in general, windows sounds. How do I avoid this sound?

Here's my form's capture of this key event...

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  C: String;
begin
  if not fChanging then
    Modified;
  if ssCtrl in Shift then begin
    C:= LowerCase(Char(Key));
    if C = 's' then begin
      DoSave;
      Key:= 0; //Tried this but didn't work
    end else
    if C = 'c' then begin
      //Copy selected item(s)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

PS - Is there a more standard way of capturing these events? Because I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, and I'm sure there's another way I should be getting these key events without sounds.

Comment: It turns out I've never taken the time to look into the action lists, which is exactly what I need to capture shortcuts (and many other things). I've known basically what it does but never used it ... until now.

Comment: Yes, always use actions for all user inoked events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Try putting your code into `FormKeyPress` instead of `FormKeyDown`. This will make the `Key := 0;` code work... You will need to handle the CTRL checking manually though, by using something like `GetKeyState()` (I originally had `GetAsyncKeyState()` here, but as Rob Kennedy points out, `GetKeyState() is a much better option)`.
- Use an Action instead. Plop a `TActionList` on your form, double click on it, add an action and set it's hot key to CTRL-S. Add your save code to it's `OnExecute` event handler. This is the "proper" way to do it I believe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use GetKeyState, not GetAsyncKeyState. The latter tells you the state of the key *right now*, whereas the former tells you the state of the key at the time the current keyboard message was *generated*. On busy systems, those two times can differ considerably.

Comment: Good point... I couldn't remember which was the best to use in the given situation...

Answer (score 2):

Here is some Delphi code to [disable the system beep](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/multimedia/enable_and_disable_system_beep.html).

Comment: But then it wouldn't be just for this scenario, it would be disabled until it's re-enabled.

Comment: +1 for good alternative reference but with ugly side-effects.

Comment: @JerryDodge...yes ugly side-effects;)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Actions? That is the best way to handle shortcuts.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge: Then be happy with it! ;)